# How do I create a duplicate user account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate user account in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/185106/duplicate-user-account-in-windows-7)

I want to set up an account on my computer for my daughter. Creating a new user in the Control Panel is easy; I've already done that. However, it's a blank slate. It would save me hours and hours of work if I could simply duplicate my own account (but non-admin of course), and then remove the things she won't need. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not really, since the stuff you want is in the Windows Registry, and copying the NTUSER files will cause conflict. You could copy the other files in your profile, but I wouldn't.

Comment: Personally, I didn't think either http://superuser.com/questions/185106/duplicate-user-account-in-windows-7 or http://superuser.com/questions/135868/creating-limited-user-account-on-windows-7 were duplicates of my question (I did read them). Anyway, Randolph's answer suggests I may have to do it the slow way.